# Macbook turns off after booting

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, startup

My Macbook was running fine today, but then powered off while I was away from it. After this, I can't get it to stay on. It turns on and then stays on for 2-3 minutes, before powering down again.

It's a MacBook 13-inch Mid 2010 model, running Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.

It's managed to reach my desktop before powering off, so doesn't seem to be a problem with booting.

I've tried taking the battery out and running it from the power cable, but this also didn't do anything.

I've also tried starting in single user and safe mode, neither or which helps.

Any ideas??

Comment: Does it show a plain white screen when you start it up?

Comment: No it starts up as usual, but then it just powers off. Managed to get it running for about an hour today before it powered down again.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that happened to my MacBook Pro 15" Early 2011, stayed on white screen for couple minutes then turned off again.
Took it to Apple and they came to the conclusion that my motherboard wasn't working so I had to get it fixed for $500 (£250 ish) and after that ever since works perfectly fine.
The cause of my problem was that it could of been my old charger (was falling apart, and so Apple replaced it for free) could of sent an electric charge that fried my motherboard.

Hope this relates or helps you to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does it always boot fully? That is, does it always make it to the desktop or does it sometimes crash/turn off while it is booting? If it's consistent, then it seems more likely that there's a software problem behind this. Have you looked at the logs in Console (Applications > Utilities > Console) to see if you can find anything suspicious? That's where I would start.

If it is inconsistent, I'd start with examining the hardware. You can run limited using Apple Hardware Test:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

I believe for a 2010 Mac you'll find the test on one of the discs that came with your computer.

Comment: Hi Margaret. It's inconsistent. Sometimes gets to desktop, sometimes doesn't. Today I got it up and running for an hour before it went down. Unfortunately I don't have the discs with me.....are there any ways to test the hardware without them?